gdb scripting for catching SIGSEGV
I try to debug a C program using gdb (not in the interactive mode). In the program, I use signal to inspect the segmentation fault, but I use gdb to find the location of the code.
If I use
gdb -ex "handle SIGSEGV stop print pass" ./script -ex "run"

It catches the error in both gdb and the program, but I need to type continue to debug the rest of the code.
If I use
gdb -ex "handle SIGSEGV nostop print pass" ./script -ex "run"

gdb only prints Thread 86241 "server-ev" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. without printing the line of code that caused the error.
I also tried config file with
define handle_sigsegv
    bt
    continue
end

but no luck.
How can I script gdb (with no interaction) to print the SIGSEGV, including the error line, and continue?

Have you tried the catch signal command?

Assuming your code looks something like this:
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void handler(int signo)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Caught signal %d\n", signo);
  signal(signo, SIG_DFL);
  raise(signo);
}

int crash()
{
  int *p = (int*)42;
  return p[0];
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
  return crash();
}

gcc -g t.c && ./a.out
Caught signal 11
Segmentation fault

Using gdb -q -batch -ex run -ex continue ./a.out:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555551b1 in crash () at t.c:14
14        return p[0];
Caught signal 11

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555551b1 in crash () at t.c:14
14        return p[0];


This approach is impractical for multithreaded programs (as it was the case for mine). continue command of gdb will continue executing the threads. However, signal(signo, SIG_DFL); will tell the kernel to crash the entire program including all threads. Therefore, we have to load the program from the beginning.

@Googlebot Your question doesn't explain what "In the program, I use signal to inspect the segmentation fault, but I use gdb to find the location of the code." means. I made a guess, but it appears an incorrect one. If you explain your setup more clearly, perhaps a better answer can be made.
